# Input Dialog Box Reappears when it is "on idle" in Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes, repeat, python-idle

I have this functionality in my Applescript wherein a input dialog box is shown to the user to enter some text. And this dialog box code is inside `"on idle" "end idle"` which repeats after every 3 seconds.

The issue is when this dialog box is shown and the user doesn't enter any details and leave the dialog box open, than after a minute or so this dialog box still remains but another dialog box appears (the same one repeats). How should I handle this issue inside `"on idle"` anyone?

Breakup of the code is shown below for reference.

```
on idle
  try           
    tell application "iTunes"
        repeat

             set loginbutton to display dialog "Enter your facebook log in name to start using XXX." default answer loginusername with title "XXX Log In" buttons {"Quit", "OK"} default button 2
             display dialog "loginbutton = " . loginbutton

             end repeat
             end tell
  end try
  return 3
end idle
```

Comment: Hmmmm... Did you try perhaps calling `quit` when you want to close the app?

Comment: A regular AppleScript will just sit there waiting for a response from the dialog - is this in AppleScript Studio or something?  The idle handler isn't really the way to go for a dialog - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just a side note, but did you declare the `loginusername` variable global?

Comment: @fireshadow52: yes quit works when i want to close the app.
`loginusername` is declared as global.

Comment: @Red_Menace: It is not done in applescript studio. A normal script file saved as "Stay open". Basically I am letting the user enter the login details and then check this from the server. If the login is incorrect then display another dialog saying that the login entered is incorrect and quit the application.

Comment: Is this possible: Disabling the input dialog box when the user does not respond to it and which does not have a timeout set?

Answer (score 1):

In regular AppleScript, when you put up a dialog the script will wait until the dialog is dismissed before continuing.  I am not able to get the symptoms you are describing, although your example snippet is incomplete and a bit buggy - you are in a repeat (forever) loop with no means of escape, since you are also trapping all errors.

The **idle** handler isn't really the place for things like this - this handler is called when your application is, well, idle, so whatever code is in it will run every time the script isn't doing anything.

if you are just wanting a dialog that repeats until a correct answer is returned, you can use something like the following in your main run handler

```
repeat -- forever
    display dialog "this is a test, so enter something with \"test\"" default answer "test"
    set theAnswer to text returned of the result
    if theAnswer contains "test" then exit repeat -- success
end repeat
log theAnswer
```

Note that although a dialog's cancel button generates a "user cancelled" error, in a stay open script the script won't quit on the error, so you will need to do your own error handling.